# Is there a way to hide a video once past a certain screen resolution?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

So I didn't realise that Chrome doesn't support media queries for videos, and this has led to the autoplaying video on my site causing issues when trying to view on smaller devices.

I'm thinking it would just be smarter to remove the video entirely past a certain resolution. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: What does _chrome doesn't support media queries for videos_ mean? What is the markup you are using for your video element?

Comment: @disinfor I quote "Video media query support has been removed from Google Chrome 34+" Granted this is old, but everything I follow still ends up doing nothing....